# add two simple indexes to optimize the query

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm newbie in SQL table optimization so i have a simple/basic question;
i have two SQL tables t1 and t2 below. If i had to add two simple indexes to optimize the query, which would should i choose ? Why ? (Please with details)

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    a int Primary Key,
    b int NOT NULL, 
    c char(10) references t2(e),
    d char(5)
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
    e char(10) Primary Key
);

SELECT a
FROM t1 JOIN
     t2 
     ON c = e
WHERE abs(b)>50
ORDER BY d;
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an index on [the expression abs(b)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html) because a simple index on `b` won't help.

The index on t1 should also include `d` in hopes of helping the order by.

The index on t1 should also include `a` and `c` to make it an [index-only scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html).

The index on t2 should include `e1` to help the join, and that should be satisfied by its primary key.

```
CREATE INDEX bk ON t1 (abs(b), d, a, c);
```

That's my attempt, but I am not a regular PostgreSQL user, and I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
    e char(10) Primary Key
);
```

`e` colum is a primary key, so you don't need to create any index here because according to [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-unique.html) the index is already there

> PostgreSQL automatically creates a unique index when a unique
>   constraint or **primary key** is defined for a table. The index covers the
>   columns that make up the primary key or unique constraint (a
>   multicolumn index, if appropriate), and is the mechanism that enforces
>   the constraint.

---

For these two condition in the query:

```
     ON c = e
WHERE abs(b)>50
```

create an index on `c` column in table `t1`.
You may also try a multicolumn-functional index on `( c, abs(b) )`, but the former should be enough. Hovewer if you decide to try it out, then remember that `c` column must be the first in the index because this column is used in `=` operator.

Comment: If `t1` is chosen to be selected first (and most likely it would) then the `c` prefix won't be used by postgresql, hence the whole composite index wouldn't be used.